# How to change the observation number with another variable?

Tags: variables, sas

I want to print the first 30 observations of my database but replace the observation number with the id number (which is another variable).

my code looks like this:

```
proc print data=data1.Donnees2005(obs=30)LABEL;
run;
```

Comment: Add NOOBS option to your PROC PRINT statement to exclude the observation numbers.

Answer (score 1):

ID idnumber;

Using ID statement will remove the default OBS column.

Answer (score 1):

```
proc print data=data1.Donnees2005(obs=30)LABEL;
    id idnumber;
run;
```